# Big theta running time of this recursive function

Tags: runtime, recurrence, big-o

I need a little help on figuring out the Big-Theta running time for this function.

```
int recursive(int n) {

    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        sum++
    if (n > 1)
        return sum + recursive(n-1);
    else
        return n;
}
```

I know how what the run time of this function would be if the for loop wasn't in the function, but the loop is throwing me off a little bit. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

- If it was just the `for` loop, not recursive, the function would be `O(n)`.
- If it was just recursive, and didn't have the `for` loop, it would also be `O(n)`.
- But, it's doing `n` recursive steps (which we know is `O(n)`) *and* it's got an `O(n)` `for` loop at each of the `n` steps.

So... does that help?

Comment: Pretty succinct and definitely spot-on.

Comment: That helps yes, but I'm still not sure if the answer is O(n^2)?